# How to integrate Angular App in Sales force canvas using Signed Request

Tags: angular, salesforce

I have an angular app hosted by asp.net core as a SPA. I need to integrate it with SalesForce Canvas using Signed Request. I understand that Salesforce does a POST to the callback URL with the signed request body which can be validated (see [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_connect.meta/platform_connect/canvas_app_unsigning_code_example.htm))). 
But Angular SPA cannot handle POSTs. It can only handle  GETs. Which among the two is a better option

1. Have Salesforce do a POST to the backend (ASP.NET Web API in our case) and redirect to the Angular App after validation from the backend.
2. Wire the ASP.NET Core FrontEnd pipeline to handle the SalesForce POST and redirect.

Is there another better way?